# Is ubuntubsd a official flavour?

Tags: canonical, bsd

I have heard about a BSD project called UbuntuBSD, i just want to know that, is that a official project of ubuntu and canonical?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not. There is a list on the Ubuntu website that tells you the offical flavors. (A search on Google for "official ubuntu flavors" yields it as the very first result.) The current list is:

> - Kubuntu
> - Edubuntu
> - Xubuntu
> - Mythbuntu
> - UbuntuStudio
> - Lubuntu
> - Ubuntu GNOME
> - Ubuntu Kylin
> - Ubuntu MATE

The list is here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors